# To prove $\inf\{\epsilon>0: A\cap S_\epsilon(B)\neq \emptyset\}=\inf\{d(a,b):a\in A,b\in B\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I want to prove the following:

For two nonempty subsets $A,B$ of a metric space $(X,d)$, the following holds $$\inf\{\epsilon>0: A\cap S_\epsilon(B)\neq \emptyset\}=\inf\{d(a,b):a\in A,b\in B\},$$
where $S_\epsilon(B)=\{y\in X:d(y,B)<\epsilon\}=\bigcup\limits_{x\in B}\{y\in X:d(x,y)<\epsilon\}$.

What I tried is:

I proved $\inf\{d(a,b):a\in A,b\in B\}\leq \inf\{\epsilon>0: A\cap S_\epsilon(B)\neq \emptyset\}$. But I am stuck how to prove $\inf\{\epsilon>0: A\cap S_\epsilon(B)\neq \emptyset\}\leq d(a,b)$ for all $a\in A,b\in B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\inf \{\epsilon >0: A\cap S_{\epsilon} (B) \neq \emptyset\} =0$ there is nothing to prove. Suppose now that this infimum  is a positive number $r$. For $0<\epsilon <r$ we have
$A\cap S_{\epsilon} (B) = \emptyset$ Hence, for every $a \in A, b \in B$ we have $d(a,b) \geq \epsilon$. Letting $\epsilon $ increase to $r$ we conclude that $d(a,b) \geq r$ for all $b \in B$.